# $n$-th derivative of $e^{ax} \sin(bx+c)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the $n$th derivative of the following function:

$$f(x) =  e^{ax}\sin(bx+c) $$

I tried using product rule a few times and see if there was a pattern but couldn't find any and I also tried generating a Taylor series and all but it didn't really work as I need to find the $n$th derivative of all $x$values not just $0$.

I might have done something wrong but I'm not sure.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an explicit formula for the $n$th derivative of $e^{ax}\sin(bx+c)$ if you start by writing $$\sin x=\frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$$

In which case, $$e^{ax}\sin(bx+c)=\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{x(a+ib)+ic}-e^{(a-ib)x-ic}\right)$$

Differentiating $n$ times, we get $$\frac{1}{2i}\left((a+ib)^ne^{x(a+ib)+ic}-(a-ib)^ne^{(a-ib)x-ic}\right)$$

Using $e^{ix}=\cos x +i\sin x$, this can be written as $$\frac{e^{ax}}{2i}\left[\left((a+ib)^n-(a-ib)^n)\right)\cos(bx+c)+i\left((a+ib)^n+(a-ib)^n\right)\sin(bx+c)\right]$$

So if you can work out powers of complex numbers, this is fairly easy to use and will give a real answer.

For example, if you want the $10$th derivative of $e^{2x}\sin(3x+c)$, you can put $n=10$, $a=2$ and $b=3$ and get$$-e^{2x}[145668\cos(3x+c)+341525\sin(3x+c)]$$

Answer (score 1):

n-th derivative of $f(x)=e^{ax}\sin(bx+c)$ will be imaginary part of $e^{ax}\times e^{i(bx+c)}=e^{(a+bi)x+ci}$.

So, it will be...
$$\Im((a+bi)^ne^{(a+bi)x+ci})$$

Comment: But like how can the derivative be a complex number? I'm only in high school so my understanding of complex numbers etc. are pretty basic but would love to learn about it

Comment: @DashikKumar It is complex-valued real variable function, so there's not much difference between real-valued real variable function. just differentiate it.